# find and replace values of an array, VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, replace, ms-word

Let assume I have an array something like this:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
arr(0)= "Text<&>data"
arr(1)= "<&>recombining"
arr(2)= "that libraries<&>"
arr(3)= "<&>professional<&>user "
```

I would like to search inside the values and find all `<&>` and then replace them with `and`.

My efforts by `.find` were unsuccessful. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Replace$`. Not sure if you wanted to add any whitespace? I use constants as you have fixed bounds so no calls to `UBound` and `LBound` when looping the array. Also, use typed function `Replace$` as more efficient.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const START_POINT As Long = 0
    Const END_POINT As Long = 3
    Dim Arr(START_POINT To END_POINT) As Variant, i As Long
    Arr(0) = "Text<&>data"
    Arr(1) = "<&>recombining"
    Arr(2) = "that libraries<&>"
    Arr(3) = "<&>professional<&>user "

    For i = START_POINT To END_POINT
        Arr(i) = Replace$(Arr(i), "<&>", "and")
    Next
    For i = START_POINT To END_POINT
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 'Replace$' :)

GREAT! it works properly. thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid loop turning array into a string with Join(), making the replacement and finally turning it back to an array with Split() (Not tested):

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Array("Text<&>data", _
            "<&>recombining", _
            "that libraries<&>", _
            "<&>professional<&>user ")

Arr = Split(Replace$(Join(Arr, "|"), "<&>", "and"), "|")
```